# zclip is not working when i bind that on a hidden element

Tags: jquery, zclip

I want to have a copy button on my website which copies text of a div to the clipboard, since javascript does not have access to clipboard directly therefore, i'm using zclip for that, but when i bind zclip to a hidden element and when i show that element than zclip does not work or bind on that please help me out.

HTML Code:

```
<span class="homebutton">Get code for this theme</span>
<div class="get_code">
    <pre class="theme_code"><?php echo $theme['theme_code'];?></pre>
    <div class="copy_code">Copy</div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.homebutton').click(function(){
    $('.get_code').show('slow');
});

$('.copy_code').zclip({
    path: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function(){return $('.theme_code').text();},
    afterCopy: function() {}
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if its not working with hidden field then make it show with `.show()` and then initialise `zclip` on it.

Comment: i tried that too but did not work for me. Thanks for giving your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution i tried binding the event on setTimeout function and it worked as i needed.. :)

I'm sharing that code hope it will help other people!

HTML code:

```
<span class="homebutton">Get code for this theme</span>
<div class="get_code">
    <pre class="theme_code"><?php echo $theme['theme_code'];?></pre>
    <div class="copy_code">Copy</div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.homebutton').click(function(){
    $('.get_code').show('slow');
    setTimeout(function(){bind_zclip();},1000);
});

function bind_zclip()
{
    $('.copy_code').zclip({
        path: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy: function(){return $('.theme_code').text();},
        afterCopy: function() {}
    });
}
```